# Cause by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException no such table: Category (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT *FROM Category WHERE tag =?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my app i used sqlite db file for getting some data. It works fine for most of the users but some of them getting crash **Cause by:** android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: getCtgList (code 1): ,

> while compiling: "SELECT *FROM Category WHERE tag =?", new String[]{string}"

Below is my SQLite DBHelper class to create and copy database. in asster/font.db has a **Category** table . after copying this table some of device missing this table. I searched a lot to fix this error but didn't find any solution. and I'm getting trending issues for app crashing on google play store. Please help me to fix this error.

Code:

```
package com.softtechbd.nickname_finder.Database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String location = "/data/data/com.com.softtechbd.stylishnicknamegenerator/databases";
    private static final String DB_Name = "font_data.db";
    private static final int DB_Ver = 2;
    private Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Object String;

    public DBHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DB_Name, null, DB_Ver);
        this.mContext= context;
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        if (databaseExists() ){
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
            int dbVersion = prefs.getInt("db_ver", 1);
            if (DB_Ver != dbVersion) {
                File dbFile = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_Name);
                if (!dbFile.delete()) {
                    Log.w("dbexists", "Unable to update database");
                }
            }
        }
        if (!databaseExists()){
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDatabase();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            copyDatabase();
            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.

        }
    }

    private void copyDatabase(){
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_Name);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    "/data/data/"+mContext.getPackageName()+"/databases/"+DB_Name);
            byte[]arrby = new byte[1024];
            do {
                int n;
                if((n=inputStream.read(arrby)) <=0 ){
                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences((mContext)).edit();
                    editor.putInt("db_ver",DB_Ver);
                    editor.apply();
//                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "SQLite DB copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                fileOutputStream.write(arrby,0,n);
            }while (true);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void closeDatabase(){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.database;
        if(sqLiteDatabase!= null){
            sqLiteDatabase.close();
        }
    }


    private boolean databaseExists() {
        File dbFile = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_Name);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
    public void openDatabase(){
        String string = this.mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_Name).getPath();
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.database;
        if(sqLiteDatabase!=null && sqLiteDatabase.isOpen()){
            return;
        }
        this.database=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(string,null,0);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getSymbols() {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        openDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT *FROM symbols ", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            arrayList.add(cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("content")));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        closeDatabase();
        return arrayList;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getHotName (){
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        openDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT *FROM hot_names", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            arrayList.add(cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("contents")));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        closeDatabase();
        return arrayList;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getList(String string){
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.openDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = this.database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM emotication_detail WHERE parent_id =?",new String[]{string});
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){

            arrayList.add( cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("content")) );
//            item sample = new item(cursor.getInt(0),cursor.getString(1));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        this.closeDatabase();
        return arrayList;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCtgList (String string){
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        openDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT *FROM Category WHERE tag =?", new String[]{string});
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            arrayList.add(cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("content")));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        closeDatabase();
        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

> Error log:

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Category (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT *FROM Category WHERE tag =?
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1408)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1347)
       at com.softtechbd.nickname_finder.Database.DBHelper.getCtgList(DBHelper.java:18)
       at com.softtechbd.nickname_finder.Fragments.pick_category_list.onCreateView(pick_category_list.java:4)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.R(Fragment.java:15)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:27)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.b0(FragmentManagerImpl.java:49)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:42)
       at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:6)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:7)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:88)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:4)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6758)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:497)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:912)
```

Comment: 1st  u need to check database exists or not \n
2nd check log while copy database \n & 
3rd check Table Name (spelling) \n
because Error : `QLiteException: no such table: Category (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing :-

```
private boolean databaseExists() {
    File dbFile = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_Name);
    return dbFile.exists();
}
```

to :-

```
private boolean databaseExists() {
    File dbFile = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_Name);
    if (dbFile.exists()) {
        return true;
    }
    dbFile.mkdirs(); //<<<<<<<<<< creates the databases folder
    return false;
}
```

along with removing the line `this.getReadableDatabase();`

The use of `getReadableDatabase` *(or getWritableDatabase as they are effectively the same in most siutations)* hides the real underlying issue which is that the **databases** folder not existing results in the copy failing. That is `getReadableDatabase` will create the missing **databases** folder.

Although this works for older devices, newer devices (Android 9+) default to using write-ahead logging (WAL). If a database is created using WAL then two additional files, the WAL file (database file name suffixed with -wal) and the shared memory file (database file name suffixed with -shm) are created.

If just the database file is overwritten (as per the comments) then the -wal file is incompatible with the new database and the attempt to open the  database fails, the failure is captured and instead an empty database file is created and returned and hence the loss of any tables. **Hence the issue that you are facing**.

Creating the **databases** folder if the database file does not exist, eliminates the need to use getReadable database to create the **databases** folder and thus the creation of -wal and -shm files. Thus why getReadableDatabase should not be used prior to the copy of the assets file.

- Alternately you could delete the -wal and -shm files if they exist, prior to the copy.

i.e. the comments

- WAL instead of recording changes in the log allowing them to be rolled back (journal mode) writes the changes to the WAL file and they are applied to the actual database when committed, thus the WAL file is effectively part of the database (roll back is effectively deleting WAL file). You may wish to refer to https://sqlite.org/wal.html

I would also suggest NOT hard coding the database path in the line

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/"+mContext.getPackageName()+"/databases/"+DB_Name);
```

but instead use `mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME)` to get the path.

e.g.

```
FileOutputSream fileOutputStrean = new FileOutputStream(mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME));
```

Note the above code has not been tested so it may contain some errors, rather it is the principle that is being communicated.

An alternative approach could be to force journal mode using the journal_mode pragma or the `SQliteDatabase` `disableWriteAheadLogging` method. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#disableWriteAheadLogging()